# How to append my HTML code into div correctly?

Tags: html, jquery, append

I have a problem in which when I append some elements (a table with two input type=text and a button) to a div tag, my elements move and go into the wrong place.
My code:

```
<div id="tables"></div>
<script>
var HTML_new_group = '\
<h4>'+gpName+'</h4>\
<table border="1">\
    <thead>\
        <tr>\
            <td>option</td>\
            <td>value</td>\
        </tr>\
    </thead>\
    <tbody>\
        <tr>\
            <td><input type="text" class="np-gp-option" data-np-gp-option-id="'+gpId+'"></td>\
            <td><input type="text" class="np-gp-value" data-np-gp-value-id="'+gpId+'"></td>\
        </tr>\
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="np-gp-add" data-np-gp-add-id="'+gpId+'" />\
    </tbody>\
</table>';
$(HTML_new_group).appendTo("#tables");
</script>
```

[Final code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG8bP.png)

[Final view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvyI7.png)

As you can see, the button is at the top of the table

Comment: Having an input as a direct child on tbody is not correct

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Oh thanks. I moved the button down from the table and it works now

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a formatted text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635). You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how do you format your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are appending an input in table without specifying the tr and td for it. See the last input that you have added. Wrap it in tr and a td it will be appended there in table.

```
var HTML_new_group = '\
<h4>'+gpName+'</h4>\
<table border="1">\
    <thead>\
        <tr>\
            <td>option</td>\
            <td>value</td>\
        </tr>\
    </thead>\
    <tbody>\
        <tr>\
            <td><input type="text" class="np-gp-option" data-np-gp-option-id="'+gpId+'"></td>\
            <td><input type="text" class="np-gp-value" data-np-gp-value-id="'+gpId+'"></td>\
        </tr>\
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" class="np-gp-add" data-np-gp-add-id="'+gpId+'" /></td></tr>\
    </tbody>\
</table>';
```